# NVIZ runs from GRASS but not via QGIS

Tags: qgis

When I try to run NVIZ from QGIS I get an error which states 'Can't find usable init.tcl in the following directories" and then goes on to list a number of directories. (I did have a screenshot here but couldn't post it as a newbie.)

However when I try to run NVIZ directly from GRASS it runs properly.  I have searched for the init file which the QGIS error report says cannot be found and it is actually in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\lib\tcl8.5".  According to the QGIS error report this is not one of the directories actually searched.  I do have a workaround running NVIZ from GRASS but that is clearly not as satisfactory as running from within QGIS.  I have noted the reply to an earlier question on this topic which recommends installing tcl/tk via OSGEO4W. However I do not believe that these components are actually missing since I've found the init file.

Can anyone suggest a solution, please? I am a new user of QGIS and have downloaded 1.8.0 Lisboa, running under Windows 7.

Comment: I have the same problem - did you eventually find a solution to the problem?